# Contesting the Race: Would the U.S. Supreme Court Intervene?

Tags: united-states, supreme-court

After reading commentary on the implausibility of rendering a U.S. presidential election void (and the post, *Is it possible to rig the American presidential elections?*), I have a question. Considering the fact that the 1887 Electoral Count Act generally gives power to individual states to determine disputed election results, what would be the point of a candidate contesting a particular state’s election?  Even in a close race, if a candidate this week successfully challenges a state’s election results (such as proof of vote fraud),  would the U.S. Supreme Court intervene?

Comment: Could you add links to the articles you mentioned?

Answer (score 2):

Possibly. One could argue to the Supreme Court that something a State was doing regarding their election results violated some Federally protected right of its citizens. For example, in the 2000 election, the Florida recount was [challenged at the Supreme Court](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bush_v._Gore) which decided that the proposed recount violated the Constitutionally-guaranteed right of equal protection.